# jhipster generates required fields as not required in typescript types

Tags: typescript, jhipster, typescript-typings, jdl

I am using the jhipster generator to automatically generate Typescript types. Recently I've noticed that the generator has some behavior I did not expect. I have the following jdl code:

```
entity MeasurementResult {
    frequencies Float required
}
```

which generates following typescript interface out of it:

```
interface IMeasurementResult {
    frequency?: number
}
```

Now my question is why is it generated with a "?" (indicating it can be undefined), while it is defined as required in the jdl file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the JHipster team decided to make all fields optional (`?`) because form validation takes care of model correctness anyway. You can see exactly where the generator does this [here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/2ac3cfa2f09a7585f69c72558f4aa9e19d3ad178/generators/generator-base-private.js#L926).

This means that, for example, near the top of your `update.component.ts` you will find a `Validators.required` on that field definition. Everything is validated again server-side.